# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting the following error while building signed APK

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForRelease'
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: 
com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain$ToolchainException: Jack configuration exception.
Error while parsing '/Users/omprakash/.android/build-cache/44cf3550bd071d5e2184a0fbb6e8da24ff70e1cb/output/proguard.txt':2
```

The app is running fine in debug mode.

But when I am building the signed APK I am getting the above error. Tried changing the buildToolVersion but it didn't help. I also have MyApplication class extending MultiDexApplication.

The following is my gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.omagrahari"

    manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "9727c212-****-****-**********",
                            // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                            onesignal_google_project_number: "21051******"]
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
dexOptions {
    incremental true
    preDexLibraries false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})



compile('com.zendesk:sdk:1.11.0.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
compile 'com.cjj.materialrefeshlayout:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.cocosw:bottomsheet:1.+@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
compile 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.43'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.4.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
}
```

I don't get how to solve this. Please help.

Comment: Seems like your proguard file is having some issues, post it too

Comment: I haven't made any change to the progaurd file

Comment: hey man @OmPrakashAgrahari were you able to resolve this issue, cause I'm having it at the moment and its really pissing me off

Comment: Yes @XY-JOE . It was because of zendesk and JackOptions. I removed JackOptions because I think Zendesk doesn't support JackOtions. They have a solution for it but it didn't work for me either.

Comment: @OmPrakashAgrahari Thanks a lot for the quick response. I just figured it out. Thanks a lot. JackOption really messed me up